# In trying to setup back up device, net use command throws operating system error 53 when passing in a unc

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, backup

So I'm trying to use XP_CMDSHELL to set up my drive for using a backup.  I already have the drive mapped, but per [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160307070949/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/varund/archive/2009/06/04/backup-sql-server-database-to-a-share-drive-on-another-server.aspx), I figured I'd need to mount the drive using net use.

But when I do, I get System error 53, 'The network path was not found.'

```
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'net use S: \\sql-backup'
```

I know this unc is accessible from the server because it is mounted as a network share on the sql server.

Any ideas why the unc is unreachable?

Comment: Why don't you just backup straight to the UNC path, use that in your backup command, in place of mapping it?

Comment: +1 Shawn. There's no reason to use xp_cmdshell for this. Honestly, with all the tools available (CLRs, SSIS, the ability to invoke the command shell via the agent, Powershell...), there's really no legitimate reason to use xp_cmdshell. xp_cmdshell was a good "pre SQL 2005" tool that, for security reasons, most experts now recommend disabling.

Answer (score 2):

You have to give it both the server name *and* a shared folder, i.e., `\\Server\SharedFolder`.

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to check to see if the account identity for the SQL Service has access to that network share.